# Is it impermissible for women to run/jog between safa and marwa (during hajj/umrah saee)?

Tags: hajj, umrah

According to the [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175579/reason-why-men-run-in-sai-between-as-safa-and-al-marwah) women do not run between safa and marwa as it may lead to immodesty.

> Women, however, do not run, because they are required to cover themselves and be modest, and running may expose their bodies and their charms

Furthermore [they say](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/109286/it-is-not-permissible-for-a-woman-to-trot-during-tawaaf-or-saai):

> Ibn al-Mundhir said: The scholars are unanimously agreed that women do not have to trot around the Ka’bah or between al-Safa and al-Marwah

From my understanding, Islamqa suggests its not obligatory for the women to run/jog.

1. Is it **impermissible** for her to run/jog out of remembrance for Hajar ? (provided she can manage to not uncover)
2. if yes, is it a sunnah(rewarding) if she runs/jogs?

I haven't found a prohibition from Hadith hence my question since the very act men are mimicking was done by a woman (Hajar).

(Looking for Sunni answers)

Comment: Be aware that moving fast for men is a recommendation not something which they should or have to do, not doing it is not sinful as it was reported by ibn 'Omar in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/11/184) and also by a-Thirmidhi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not prescribed and is against the sunnah for women to run.

> عن عائشة أنها سئلت: على النساء رمل؟ فقالت: أليس لكن بنا أسوة؟ ليس عليكن رمل بالبيت، ولا بين الصفا والمروة
>
> Ayesha was asked: Should women do Raml?
>
> She said: Is our way not made an example for you? Not on you is Raml of the House (in tawaf), nor between Safa and Marwa.
>
> <sup>— [مصنف ابن أبي شيبة](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/14488#p1)</sup>

Comment: what should they do then? walk?